# Kronecker lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $f$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $1$ in $K[X]$. 
Then there is some field $L$, $K\in L$ such that $f$ has at least one root in $L$.

The solution proceeds by taking the quotient ring $K/ f$. Then we can easily prove that  $ X"$ is a root for $f$ in $K/f$.

In the past I thought we define a quotient ring by taking the quotient group of the additive group of the ring with respect to some normal subgroup and then define the multiplication and check they are well defined and respect the axioms of a ring, etc.

> Is this a slightly different way of defining a quotient ring (i.e., defining residues modulo a polynomial in $K[X]$)?

Comment: $f$ need not be of degree 1, otherwise the construction is pointless (since $deg(f) = 1\implies f$ has a root in $K$). Moreover, the quotient is $K[X]/(f)$, where $(f)$ is the ideal generated by $f$, which is an additive subgroup of $K[X]$, and since $(K[X],+)$ is abelian, it's a normal subgroup. So this is the same construction as the one you know

Comment: thank you!.  probably a stupid question: can we actually define $K/f$ ,like a residue class, or do we need indeed  a subring?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "do we need indeed a subring ?"

Comment: got it . just took a while=) . thanks a lot!